# draw an arc from endpoints of line and fill in

Tags: swift, core-graphics

[image]I did the following:

```
    let xOrigin = (pointsOfPerformance[POP.gluteusMaximus.index].x_origin / 375) * self.view.bounds.width
    let yOrigin = (pointsOfPerformance[POP.gluteusMaximus.index].y_origin / 666.6666) * (self.view.bounds.width * 16 / 9)
    let p0 = CGPoint(x: xOrigin, y: yOrigin)
    let xDest = (pointsOfPerformance[POP.upperBack.index].x_origin / 375) * self.view.bounds.width
    let yDest = (pointsOfPerformance[POP.upperBack.index].y_origin / 666.6666) * (self.view.bounds.width * 16 / 9)
    let p1 = CGPoint(x: xDest, y: yDest)
    
    let midPoint = CGPoint(x: (xOrigin + xDest) / 2, y:
                            (yOrigin + yDest) / 2)
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: p0)
    path.addLine(to: p1)
    
    path.addArc(withCenter: p2, radius: 94, startAngle: 200, endAngle: 130, clockwise: true)
    let centerOfCircle = makePoint(xOffset: p2.x, yOffset: p2.y)
    view.addSubview(centerOfCircle)
    
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.animationRed.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.animationRed.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.05
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

How do I get the circle to only show up as a slice of its curve that comes off the line on the back. It's unclear how I manipulate the function to get only the part coming off the line on the back visible.

Comment: Have you tried: func addArc(withCenter center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, clockwise: Bool). That's supposed to work with UIBezierPath.

Comment: Hi. When I try that I can only get a whole circle to appear.

Comment: If you're getting a circle, try decreasing the end angle.  eg, use startAngle: 0 and endAngle:180 (not endAngle:360)

Comment: Example code edited to show another appendArc function (hopefully the one that you are using).

Comment: Thanks apodidae. I got the function working in that it draws a circle. But I've modified my post to illustrate what I'm struggling with. Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Leave center of circle where it is and adjust the start and end angles so that they are about eighty degrees apart.  See answer 3.

Answer (score 0):

This works on MacOS:

```
 class CustomView: NSView {
   override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
     let bkgrnd = NSBezierPath(rect: rect)
     let fillColor = NSColor.white
     fillColor.set()
     bkgrnd.fill()
          
     let center = NSMakePoint(rect.size.width/2,rect.size.height/2)
     let radius:CGFloat = rect.size.width/4

     let path1 = NSBezierPath()
     path1.appendArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 90, endAngle: 270)
     NSColor.gray.set()
     path1.fill()

     let path2 = NSBezierPath()
     path2.appendArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 270, endAngle: 90)
     NSColor.blue.set()
     path2.fill()
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Demonstrates getting a small slice of the periphery of a circle for MacOS:

```
class CustomView: NSView {
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect ) {
 let bkgrnd = NSBezierPath(rect: rect)
 let fillColor = NSColor.white
 fillColor.set()
 bkgrnd.fill()

 let center = NSMakePoint(rect.size.width/2,rect.size.height/2)
 let radius:CGFloat = rect.size.width/4

 let circle = NSBezierPath()
 circle.appendArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360)
 NSColor.gray.set()
 circle.fill()

 let arc = NSBezierPath()
 arc.appendArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 120, endAngle: 200)
 NSColor.blue.set()
 arc.fill()
 }
}
```